# XML Parser Error: not well formed (invalid token)

Tags: python, xml, parsing, elementtree

I am trying to create an xml tree from string.

I am trying to create a root of the tree. below is code:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

r="""<root nsp="suan2.0" nsp:host="1" id='%s'></root>""" %obj['value']
root = ET.fromstring(r,ET.XMLParser())
```

Result if I print variable r.

```
<root nsp="suan2.0" nsp:host="1" id='newapp'></root>
```

Stacktrace for error received in logs.

```
anaconda3\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py,line 1342,in XML parser.feed(text)
    xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError:not well formed (invalid token)
```

Comment: What does `r` look like **after** substituting the value of `obj['value']`?

Comment: @larsks Edited my post and added the result for variable r after I print it.

Comment: Works for me with Python3 version 3.10.7: `print(root.tag, root.attrib)` returns "root {'nsp': 'suan2.0', 'host': '1', 'id': '5'}". (Using `%5` instead of `%obj['value']`).

Comment: Indeed, this works perfectly fine using `"""<root nsp="suan2.0" host="1" id='newapp'></root>"""` as content for `r`.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I missed adding colon in the string variable r. That is leading to this issue. I don't know yet how I can resolve this issue. Edited my question now.

Comment: Your code and sample output don't match. When you ask a question, you need to include code that runs and reproduces the problem you're asking about (read about [mcve]). E.g., in your code, you have attribute `nsp:host` (which is invalid because you have no namespace declarations), but in your output, you have only `host`.

Comment: @larsks Have made the correction.

Comment: The code in your question fails with, `xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: unbound prefix: line 1, column 0` (because of the issue I mentioned in my previous comment).

Comment: @larsks Does namespace cause this issue when I try to parse the variable r. I have been observing this issue only comes up when I am using a namespace.

Answer (score 0):

This works without not well formed XML Error, compare [doc namespace](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#sec-namespaces). The `xmlns` should reference to a url e.g. "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/". On this link you can read "Note that you **must** use the reserved prefix **xmlns:** when declaring namespaces. It does not work to declare another prefix with this namespace name and then try to use it for namespace declarations."

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

obj={'value':'newapp'}
r= """<root xmlns="suan2.0" xmlns:host="1" id="%s"></root>""" %obj['value']
print(r)
root = ET.fromstring(r,ET.XMLParser())
```

Output:

```
<root xmlns="suan2.0" xmlns:host="1" id="newapp"></root>
```